# How to load a file in IWMPPlayer without playing it?

Tags: windows, activex, windows-media-player

I've got a project that uses [`IWMPPlayer4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the ActiveX interface to Windows Media Player.  Downloading and playing a video from the Internet is easy: just call [`put_URL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and it connects to the video and begins to play it.

But what if I want to tell it to load up a video from a certain URL but *not* begin to play it yet?  It's not clear from the documentation I've seen how I would do that, but I figure there has to be a way to accomplish it.  Does anyone know how?

I tried calling [`get_controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then either the `Pause` or `Stop` methods on the resulting IWMPControls interface immediately after calling `put_URL`, but both caused the same problem:  no media actually loaded, and clicking the Play button on-screen plays nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've worked with WMP API's, but I think you want this:

[IWMPSettings::put_autoStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563670%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

From the MSDN link above:

> You should set put_autoStart to FALSE immediately before you set
>   IWMPCore::put_URL, IWMPCore::put_currentPlaylist, or
>   IWMPCore::put_currentMedia in skins and remoted Player controls if you
>   wish to ensure that the media item does not start playing immediately.
>   Also, unless you set put_autostart to TRUE immediately before
>   specifying a media item, you should not rely on this setting as a
>   substitute for using the IWMPControls::play method.

Comment: This seems to have the same basic problem: I say `put_autoStart(false)`, and then when I hit the Play button in the UI, nothing plays.  Strangely, this only seems to happen the first time; after loading other media, it works.  Is there some sort of initialization I'd need to run or something?

Comment: @MasonWheeler - I suspect that you need to keep your play button disabled until the content (specified by the URL) is ready to be played. That is IWMPCore::get_status() will return "ready" (I forget the actual state string).  You can use IWMPEvents::StatusChange notification to find out when the status has changed so you know when to refresh the UI and enable the button.